# Stop rendering or freeze view for a specified DOM element

Tags: javascript

I like to stop rendering for a specified dom element while i changing values to prevent flickering. Is this possible ? I can use html2canvas to create a screenshot an show it while i changing the DOM, but seems to me like a overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detach the element, change it, then re-attach it.

```
function makeChanges(elem,changes) {
    var p = elem.parentNode, n = elem.nextSibling;
    p.removeChild(elem);
    changes(elem); // changes is a function containing the changing of values
    p.insertBefore(elem,n);
}
```

Comment: is it still visible after detach ?

Comment: i can make a clone. But i was hoping for a more beautiful way. Anyway still is an answer.

Comment: @Kolink The DOM updates when told to. This function will redraw when you remove the child and will redraw again when the insertBefore is called.